# I tried to run command "npm run start " and it showd up with this error in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bookbhandar@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bookbhandar@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Laxman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-22T18_25_37_539Z-debug.log

**Can some one help me with this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `react-scripts` is not installed into your `node_modules` folder. Try to check if you are running the command on the correct folder and if the `react-scripts` dependency is in the `package.json` file.

Otherwise try to delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`.